# Geometry - angle w.r.t. two planes to 3D pose?

Tags: geometry

I have a machine which rotates a tool about two axes, A and B.  This is defined by two pivoting angles, $A$ and $B$.  I would like to use $A$ and $B$, which rotate around a "virtual pivot point," to calculate the pose of the tool w.r.t. the origin.

A photo of the toolhead with the A and B axes labeled is here:

[image]

What is the sequence of steps I need to take?

Comment: Can you provide a picture? It's hard to understand what is given and what you want to find from the given description.

Comment: You define $A$ to be two different things, and don't tell us what $I$, $J$, and $K$ are at all. A picture would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by “the axis of $A$” when you’ve described $A$ as an angle?

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- I added a photo of the machine.  Hopefully this clears up what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write down the matrices of rotations corresponding to axes B and A ([axis-angle to rotation matrix formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rotation_matrix#/Axis_and_angle)), then composite rotation has matrix that is the product of A and B:
$$R=AB,$$

note here: matrix B has axis corresponding to the state prior to rotation around A.

After that you can transform the rotation matrix $R$ to whatever representation you like ([to Euler angles](http://www.gregslabaugh.net/publications/euler.pdf), [to axis-angle](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToAngle/)).